# In-App Billing ANE from Timeline

Tags: android, actionscript-3, in-app-billing, flash-cc

i've been trying to understand how to use Milkman's In-app billing ANE (Android) for quite some time now (some might remember my previous questions)but for the life of me, I can't make it work. 
I code using Flash CC. Since I don't yet fully grasp Document Class and such, I'm still coding in the first frame of the timeline. My app is ready and only misses that feature, so I really hope someone will be able to help me. 
I don't need something really fancy, just an example of how to set up the one-time billing. I've linked the ANE to the fla and created the object in google play console.

I don't usually ask for people to make my code for me (i'm a firm believer that explanations are better than just giving away answers in the long term), but in this case, I'm so frustrated that I would welcome it (and I will probably learn from it). 
Here is my test fla file: [test fla](https://mega.co.nz/#!XYoDRJZb!x6H3JMGwSB0mcnJ6LxwxalC0FDLjaENIaNHJzJ-4VAw) and my (not working) code for those that don't have flash installed:

```
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.android.*;
import com.milkmangames.nativeextensions.android.events.*;
import flash.events.Event;

if (AndroidIAB.isSupported()) {
    AndroidIAB.create();
} else {
    trace("no");
    return
}

// listeners for billing service startup
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.addEventListener(AndroidBillingEvent.SERVICE_READY, onReady);
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.addEventListener(AndroidBillingEvent.SERVICE_NOT_SUPPORTED, onUnsupported);
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.addEventListener(AndroidBillingEvent.INVENTORY_LOADED, onInventoryLoaded);
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.addEventListener(AndroidBillingErrorEvent.LOAD_INVENTORY_FAILED, onInventoryFailed);
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.addEventListener(AndroidBillingEvent.PURCHASE_SUCCEEDED, onPurchaseSuccess);
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.addEventListener(AndroidBillingErrorEvent.PURCHASE_FAILED, onPurchaseFailed);

// start the service
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.startBillingService("LICENCE");

function onReady(e: AndroidBillingEvent): void {
    ready.text = "Service Ready";

}

// load the player's current inventory
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.loadPlayerInventory();

function onInventoryLoaded(e: AndroidBillingEvent): void {
    for each(var purchase: AndroidPurchase in e.purchases) {
        inventory.text = "You own the item:" + purchase.itemId;

    }
}

function onInventoryFailed(e: AndroidBillingErrorEvent): void {
    inventory.text = "Something went wrong loading inventory: " + e.text;
}

// listen for purchase events

function onPurchaseSuccess(e: AndroidBillingEvent): void {
    var purchase: AndroidPurchase = e.purchases[0];
    purchased.text = "you purchased the item " + purchase.itemId;
    AndroidIAB.androidIAB.loadPlayerInventory();
}

function onPurchaseFailed(e: AndroidBillingErrorEvent): void {
    purchased.text = "Something went wrong with the purchase of " + e.itemId + ": " + e.text;
}

buyTest.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fnBuy);
function fnBuy(e: Event): void {
    click.text="clicked!!"
    AndroidIAB.androidIAB.purchaseItem("your_itemid");

}


function onUnsupported(e: AndroidBillingEvent): void {
    ready.text = "Service Not Suported";
}
```

Can someone help me set up Milkman ANE (or any other ANE for IAB) from the Timeline (without a Document Class or external classes)? Thank you very much.

Comment: Using a Document Class or external classes is exactly the same as if you use Timeline (you will need to import external classes anyway). Could you point exactly the problem you are facing with the implementation? I just checked the Milkman ANE (in App purchase) documentation and it has a very good tutorial and code example.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I used the tutorial given by Milkman to do the code I linked. I agree with you, it appears to be good and for someone with a little experience, it is probably clear. But I'm learning as I go and I have no idea what doesn't work. When I start my test app on a device registered to my developper account, i get confirmation that the service is available (function onReady); but after that, nothing works. I don't get any error, but nothing happens. I'm lost (as you probably noticed) and stuck. :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely what you need help with is with the AS3 Event system not with that particular ANE. A listener of an Event in AS3 might run at a later time. This is because AS3 is an asynchronous language. That ANE can only perform once it's ready which correctly runs the onReady listener but that's about all your code does at that point. You probably expect the line:

```
AndroidIAB.androidIAB.loadPlayerInventory();
```

to run after that but you would be wrong to think so. That line of code has already run and since the ANE wasn't ready when it did it never triggered your onInventoryLoaded listener. Placing code after methods/listener does not guaranty that things will run in that order. In your case all your code except methods and listeners will just run first (yes including AndroidIAB.androidIAB.loadPlayerInventory();), then your methods will run when called, then your listeners will run when triggered.

To ensure that code runs in correct order, because AS3 is an asynchronous, you have to wait for an event to trigger before you can try to trigger more event.

So you wait for the onReady to trigger and THEN you try to run the next step:

```
function onReady(e: AndroidBillingEvent): void {
    ready.text = "Service Ready";
    //ANE is ready let's try to load the inventory now.
    AndroidIAB.androidIAB.loadPlayerInventory();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this explantion, it is incredibly useful. I'm going to put this in application. This changes the way my whole approach (used to think everything was streamlined (not sure about the word, english is not my language)). This wiil help a lot in the future. I'll come back with the results.